# Sed works standalone but not in command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, echo, command-substitution

When I use the following command in Bash, it works fine:

```bsh
sed -n '/##/{p; :loop n; /##/q; p; b loop}' FILENAME.txt
```

It outputs something like this:

```
##

* Some line
```

### Command substitution

However, when I try to use the same command in a command substitution, it suddenly fails completely:

```
echo $(sed -n '/##/{p; :loop n; /##/q; p; b loop}' FILENAME.txt)
```

This instead prints out all of the files in my working directory in a row and then `Some line` at the end, which I have *no* clue how that would even happen:

```
 FILENAME.txt OTHER_FILE.exe dir Some line
```

---

How can I make this work? It is crucial for me that the output of `sed` is echoed with some prefix.

Comment: You need quotes `"$(sed -n '/##/{p; :loop n; /##/q; p; b loop}' FILENAME.txt)"` to prevent word-splitting and pathname expansion

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you! That did the job - I thought I had tried that, but I had only tried them at other places apparently :) Do you mind writing an answer that I can accept?